# jsp , servlets y jstl

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Tengo una duda sobre el uso de jstl.

En mi proyecto estoy empleando el uso de jstl, basándome en un ejemplo que encontré en la nube. Pero me di la sorpresa que no me funciona correctamente, por lo cual solicito su apoyo.

El problema es que la lista que envío desde mi servlet a través de un `request.setAttribute` a mi jsp , no lo captura mi jstl o en realidad no sé qué puede ser.

Aquí les dejo lo que he implementado para que tengan una idea de lo que hablo.

El post de mi servlet

```
 private static String Factores = "/frmFactores.jsp";
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String forward="";
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        List<Factor> factores = RiesgosNeg.Instancia().ListarFactores();
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
            int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
            // dao.deleteUser(userId);
            forward = Factores;
            request.setAttribute("factores",factores);
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
            //forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
            //int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
            //User user = dao.getUserById(userId);
            request.setAttribute("factores", factores);
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listFactor")){
            forward = Factores;
            request.setAttribute("factores",factores);
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("factores",factores);
        }

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        view.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

El jsp

```
<c:if test="${!empty factores}">
    <c:forEach items="${factores}" var="f">
        <tr>                                          
            <td class="text-center"><c:out value="${f.Descripcion}"/></td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${f.estado == 1}" >
                        <!-- <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"> -->
                        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <!-- <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"> -->
                        <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center" data-id="<c:out value="${f.codigo}"/>">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle edit" title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle remove" title="Eliminar"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Mi js donde llamo al servlet para llamar a mi servlet desde el momento que selecciono mi pagina

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // Si en vez de por post lo queremos hacer por get, cambiamos el $.post por $.get
    $.post('../sRiesgos', {
        action: 'listFactor'
    }, function (responseText) {
        // $('#tblFactores').html(responseText);
    }); });
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el atributo `"factores"` no está vacío y es alcanzable desde tu página JSP? Podrías hacer una prueba de Expression Language usando `${factores.size}` en alguna parte del JSP, si da un resultado entonces significa que la variable sí se puede alcanzar y que el problema está en otro lado.

Comment: He puesto  :  <c:out value="${factores.size}"/>  y no me aparece nada.

Comment: No necesitas el `c:out`. JSTL  y EL, son independientes, puedes poner solo ${factores.size} o ${factores}

Comment: ¿Estás haciendo forward a un JSP que tiene el código que muestras o este es un fragmento de JSP que se invoca desde otro código JSP quizás utilizando `<jsp:include>`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza
A un jsp. 
Tengo una carpta Riesgos (dentro de ella tengo el jsp :   frmFactores.jsp).

El esqueleto de mi jsp es el siguiente :

Y   
  ${factores.size}  , sigue sin mostrarme nada

Comment: Para debuggear, puedes insertar un codigo en tu jsp que te muestre todos los attributos (eg: http://snipplr.com/view/44314/ ) . Te recomiendo probar de agregar otro attributo dummy en el doPost() (por ejemplo, un string que muestre a cuál de los if/else estás entrando y quizas redirigir el doGet() al doPost() para probar directamente la url.

Comment: El servlet si lo he seguido los pasos, entra al if indicado  y no me manda al exception.

PD: Como hace para resaltar la linea de codigo que ponen es la respuesta. Disculpen la ignorancia :P

Comment: @leonbloy hize tal cual me enseña ese ejemplo y no me muestra ninguna información

Comment: Con respecto a los errores, los JSP pueden manejar directamente los errores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que te funcione lo que quieres hacer necesitas escribir en la sesión del request, pues como veo en tu código la misma petición que envias es la misma que estas escribiendo y no te funcionara por que al terminar la peticion los valores que escribiste se pierden asi que tendiras que hacer algo como esto:

`request.getSession().setAttribute("factores",factores);`

Ahora ya te deberia funcionar.

En mi humilde opinion creo que lo que estas haciendo esta mal aunque te funcione, por el simple hecho de que haces una petición AJAX cuando estas utilizando JSP.

Si vas a utilizar JSP y JSTL lo mejor que puedes usar es hacer un binding entre tu controlador y tu JSP para que las variables que tengas en tu controlador sean las mismas que tengas expuestas en tu JSP y puedas acceder de forma nativa a ellas.

Si prefieres utilizar AJAX en tu aplicación lo mejor es que dejes de lado JSP y te pases a frameworks y librerias hechos para ello como Angular, Ember, etc.

Comment: En realidad el servidor va a responder a la petición Ajax con un fragmento HTML que va a generar a partir del procesamiento del JSP. No me parece malo, pero sí considero que es inusual. Ahora, sé que funciona porque en uno de los proyectos en los que trabajo hay una parte implementada así (para bien o para mal, pero funciona).

Comment: A eso le llamo valor.

Comment: Podrias mostrar un ejemplo de la recomendacion que me indica. porque la unica forma que encontre para llamar a un servlet era desde un ajax . 
Pero segun me doy cuenta , cuando llamo a mi pagina desde el menu (a travez de yb href=pagina.jsp) y esa pagina carga automanticamente el servlet  y donde no me arrajo absolutamente nada.

Comment: Y bueno, es mi primer proyecto en jsp con servlet aun estoy "verde" en estos temas.  Gracias por el consejo. 
Dejare el jstl :'(

Comment: Si utilizas JSP lo mejor que puedes hacer es apegarte a su forma de trabajo que es con JSTL y EL aquí tienes un tutorial de esto:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

Ahora de el lado de javascript mas enfocado a REST aquí tienes un tutorial y un ejemplo

http://www.ingenieroperales.com/2015/12/07/primeros-pasos-con-spring-1/

https://github.com/ripper2hl/angular-todo

Comment: esos tutos con spring, desgraciadamente no puedo usar spring ='(

Comment: pues siempre estara JSF, pero no lo recomiendo, no por que sea un framework malo, si no por que la curva de aprendizaje es larga y muy probablemente quede descontinuado.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno al leer sus comentarios, los cuales les agradesco muchisimo =) . Y investigando un poco junto a mi preciada taza de café. encontre una forma de hacer mi jsp con ajax, desgraciadamente no pude user el jstl =( .

Mi jsp:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tblFactores">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd"> Agregar</button>                            
                        <thead>
                            <tr>                                    
                                <th>Factor</th>                                    
                                <th>Estado</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                      <tbody>

                        <%
                            List<Factor> listafactores = FactorNEG.Instancia().Listar();

                            for (int i = 0; i < listafactores.size(); i++) 
                            {
                                int tipo = listafactores.get(i).getCodigo();
                                out.println("<tr>");
                                out.println("<td class='text-center'>" + listafactores.get(i).getDescripcion() + "</td>");
                                if (listafactores.get(i).getEstado()== 1) {
                                    out.println("<td class='text-center'><i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i></td>");
                                } else {
                                    out.println("<td class='text-center'><i class='fa fa-square-o'></i></td>");
                                }
                               %> 
                         <td class="text-center" data-id="<%=listafactores.get(i).getCodigo()%>" >


                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle edit" title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle remove " title="Eliminar"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>

                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <%
                                 }
                                 %>
                          </tbody>  

                    </table>
```

Mi servlet :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
           String action = request.getParameter("action"); 
           Factor f = new Factor();
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("registrar")) {
           // Factor f = new Factor();
            f.setCodigo(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("codigo")));
            f.setDescripcion(request.getParameter("descripcion"));
            f.setEstado(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("estado")));
            int valor = FactorNEG.Instancia().Registrar(f);

            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            data.put("codigo",String.valueOf(valor));
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            String json = gson.toJson(data);
            response.getWriter().write(json);
        }
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete"))
        {
            f.setCodigo(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("codigo")));

            Boolean respuesta =  FactorNEG.Instancia().delete(f.getCodigo());
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            data.put("codigo",String.valueOf(respuesta));
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            String json = gson.toJson(data);
            response.getWriter().write(json);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(sFactor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

mi jsFactor

```
var oTable;
$(function () {
oTable = fn_iniciarDT(oTable, "tblFactores");
$("#btnAdd").on("click", function () {
    fn_Add();
});
oTable.on("click", ".edit", function () {
    fn_Edit(this);
});

oTable.on("click", ".save", function () {
    fn_save(this);
});

oTable.on("click", ".remove", function () {
    var elem = this;
    bootbox.confirm("\u00BFEst\u00e1 seguro de eliminar esta factor?\u003F",    function (result) {
        if (result) {
            oTable.fnDestroy();
            fn_Delete(elem);
        }
    });

});
oTable.on("click", ".cancel", function () {
    fn_Cancel(this);
});
});
function fn_Add() {
$("#tblFactores tbody").prepend("<tr>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-upload input-sm' style='width: 100%'/></td>" +
        "<td class='text-center'><input type='checkbox' checked='checked'/></td>" +
        "<td class='text-center'>" +
        "<a class='btn btn-info btn-circle save' href='javascript:;' title='Guardar' ><i  class='fa fa-save'></i></a>" +
        "<a class='btn btn-danger btn-circle cancel' href='javascript:;' title='Cancelar' ><i class='fa fa-ban'></i></a>" +
        "</td></tr>");
};
var fn_save = function (elem) {
var par = $(elem).parent().parent();
var tdnombre_factor = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
var tdestado = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
var tdbuttons = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
var id_codigo = tdbuttons.attr('data-id') === undefined ? 0 :tdbuttons.attr('data-id');

var data = {'codigo': id_codigo, 'descripcion': tdnombre_factor.children("input[type=text]").val(),
    'estado': tdestado.children("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0
};
var success = function (res) {
    if (res.codigo > 0)
    {
        tdnombre_factor.html(tdnombre_factor.children("input[type=text]").val());
        tdestado.html(res.estado === 1 ? '<i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>');
        tdbuttons.html('<a class="btn btn-primary btn-circle edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a><a class="btn btn-danger btn-circle remove"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>');
        tdbuttons.attr("data-id", res.codigo);
    }
 };
var error = function () {

    alert("error");
};
console.log(data);
fn_callmethod(base_url + "../sFactor?action=registrar", data, success, error);
};

var fn_Delete = function (elem) {

var codigo = $(elem).parent().attr('data-id') === undefined ? 0 : $(elem).parent().attr('data-id');
if (codigo !== 0) {
    var success = function (res) {
        if (res) {
            var par = $(elem).parent().parent();
            par.remove();
            oTable = fn_iniciarDT(oTable, "tblFactores");
        }
    };
    var error = function () {
    };
    fn_callmethod(base_url + "../sFactor?action=delete", {codigo: codigo}, success, error);
}
};

function fn_Edit(elem) {

var par = $(elem).parent().parent();
var tdnombre_factor = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
var tdestado = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
var tdbuttons = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
var estado;

tdnombre_factor.html("<input type='text' id='txtdescripcion' class='form-control input-sm' style='width: 100%' value='" + tdnombre_factor.html() + "'/>");
estado = tdestado.children("i").hasClass("fa-square-o") ? "<input type='checkbox'/>" : "<input type='checkbox'  checked='checked'/>";
tdestado.html(estado);
tdbuttons.html('<a class="btn btn-primary btn-circle save"><i class="fa fa-save " title="Guardar"></i></a><a class="btn btn-danger btn-circle cancel" title="Cancelar"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>');
}
;
var fn_Cancel = function (elem) {


var par = $(elem).parent().parent();
var tdbuttons = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
var id = tdbuttons.attr('data-id') === undefined ? 0 : tdbuttons.attr('data-id');

if (id === 0) {
    par.remove();
} else {
    var par = $(elem).parent().parent();
    var tdnombre_factor = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdestado = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");

    tdnombre_factor.html(tdnombre_factor.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdestado.html((tdestado.children("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked") ? '<i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>'));
    tdbuttons.html('<a class="btn btn-primary btn-circle edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a><a class="btn btn-danger btn-circle remove"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>');
}
};
```

servicios js :

```
var fn_callmethod = function(url, data, success, error) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: success,
    error: error
});
};
var fn_callmethod_get = function(url, data, success, error) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: success,
    error: error
});
};
function combo(url, id) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: base_url + url,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var option = "<option value='0'>----Seleccione----</option>";
        var tam = data.length;
        $("#" + id).append(option);
        for (var i = 0; i < tam; i++)
        {
            var option = $(document.createElement('option'));
            option.text(data[i].Descripcion);
            option.val(data[i].Codigo);
            $("#" + id).append(option);
        }
    }
});
}
var fn_iniciarDT = function(oTable, idtable) {
oTable = $("#" + idtable).dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "aLengthMenu": [[15, 25, 50, 100, -1], [15, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por p&aacute;gina",
        "zeroRecords": "Nada encontrado - lo siento",
        "info": "Mostrando la p&aacute;gina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
        "infoEmpty": "No hay registro disponibles.",
        "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado _MAX_ registros en total)",
        "sSearch": "Buscar:",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst": "Primero",
            "sLast": "Ultimo",
            "sNext": "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        }
    }
});
return oTable;
};
```

PD : 
 El unico detalle que aun no logro descubir son :

1) como validar (en la funcion add y edit creo cajas de texto y select) , la pregunta es como puedo validarlos. 
 2) Como saber si me manda un succes o error (es decir si pasa un cath en mi servlet como enviarlo como error)